# make 2d int array with values from file in java

Tags: java, multidimensional-array

I'm having problems storing a file that contains integers into a 2d int array with those values. The file has this format:

```
 1  19      36 
 1   4     212
 1   2     732
 2   9     111
 2   1      66
 2  12      29 
 2  19      14
 2  17      65
 3   2      17
 3  11      38
 3  14     122
 3  17     211
 3   1     390
 3  18      78
 3   9      11
 4   3     273  
 4   5      29   
 4  12      42 
 5   4     122
 5  16      12
```

Note there are some trailing spaces on some lines. You can check out the full file [here](https://gist.github.com/RAnders00/3f9ae4da5a6cb23ff91d).

This is what I have so far. I read the file and put each line in an array list. I thought this would be easier because then I would just be able to parse the integers out and put them into the 2d array but I've been having problems. Any suggestions?

```
private void readRoadFile()
{
    String line = null;
    try
    {
        FileReader fr = new FileReader("road.dat");
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);
        while((line = br.readLine()) != null)
        {
            roadInfo.add(line);
        }
        br.close();
    } catch(FileNotFoundException e)
    {
        System.out.println("File does not exist");
    } catch(IOException e)
    {
        System.out.println("Error reading file");
    }
}
```

Comment: What does "I have problems" mean? What's the type of `roadInfo`? Maybe a parsing of `line` helps (if you have a cast exception).

Comment: my problem is that i'm not sure how to put the information into a 2d int array. roadInfo is an array list of strings @JulianL.

Comment: Maybe you could post your file with the integers in a code block in your question, it would making a answer easier.

Comment: the image that i attached is part of the file. the numbers are in that format with that exact spacing. I'll post the file anyways though @RAnders00

Answer (score 0):

You should parse strings and transform your arraylist into an array:

```
    List<int[]> roadInfo = new ArrayList<>();

    try (BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("road.dat"))) {

        for (String line = reader.readLine(); line != null; line = reader.readLine()) {

            String[] split = line.split("\t"); // or \\s+
            int[] numbers = new int[split.length];

            for (int i = 0; i < split.length; i++) {
                numbers[i] = Integer.parseInt(split[i].trim());
            }

            roadInfo.add(numbers);
        }

    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }

    int[][] twoDArray = roadInfo.toArray(new int[roadInfo.size()][]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following solution - it uses the modern Java 8 Streams to simplify the flow of data.

```
@Override
public void run()
{
    List<List<Integer>> result = new ArrayList<>();
    try (FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream("stackoverflow-q-34096490.txt");
         InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(fileInputStream, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
         BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader))
    {
        for (String line = bufferedReader.readLine(); line != null; line = bufferedReader.readLine())
            result.add(Arrays.stream(line.split("\\s+")).filter(s -> !s.isEmpty()).map(Integer::parseInt).collect(Collectors.toList()));
    } catch (IOException ioe)
    {
        System.err.println("Read failure!");
        ioe.printStackTrace();
    }

    // use result
    System.out.println(result);
}
```